# LaTeX page numbering

Tags: header-footer

I am writing my PhD thesis and facing a strange problem: whatever I may do, all my page numbers are appearing on the top right side of the page. I want them to be in the even(left) and odd(right) format. The preamble I'm using is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{lastpage}
%\usepackage{latexsym}

%\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    anchorcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    pdfview=FitB}

%Margins and Header/Footer
\geometry{a4paper,
  top=2in,
  bottom=1in,
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  headheight=14.5pt, % the default is too short
  heightrounded, % avoids the need of a flexible baselineskip
}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}[\vspace{2ex}\titlerule]
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fonts used
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{charter}
%------------------------------
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sl\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\rm\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sl\rightmark}

...........
```

Comment: I suggest to take a look at documentclass memoir as it simplifies customization of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

You also had page numbers in the footer. Just replace

```
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sl\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\rm\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sl\rightmark}
```

with

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sl\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rm\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\sl\rightmark}
```

But since you're using `titlesec`, you might as well drop `fancyhdr` and use the `titleps` module of titlesec. In my opinion titleps makes it easier to control the formatting of the headers/footers. You can test with this code that emulates what the `fancy` page style produces:

```
\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\headrule
\sethead[\thepage][][\MakeUppercase{\slshape\thesection\quad\sectiontitle}]{\MakeUppercase{\slshape\chaptername~\thechapter\quad\chaptertitle}}{}{\thepage}
\setfoot{}{}{}
}%
\pagestyle{mine}
```